# php: How to find a count result of 1 means one element or uncountable?

Tags: php, arrays

If an array has only one element, the count result will be 1. If the array is uncountable, the result is also 1. So, How to know it's one element or uncountable?
**Edit**
php menue:  If var is not an array or an object with implemented Countable interface, 1 will be returned.

Comment: What do you mean by "uncountable"?

Comment: `print_r` it.. you'll eventually come to know ;)

Comment: Can you put an example of "uncountable" array?

Comment: for example, a function returns false. Then I use count to count the function's result, I got 1

Comment: That sounds like you implement functions that return different types. Though that is possible you should rethink if that is a good idea because it obviously means you always have to check the type of the return value before using it.

Comment: then you could do this: if ($result === false) {...} else echo count($result)...

Comment: I see. I come to understand what I should do to improve my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

> Returns the number of elements in var. If var is not an array or an
>   object with implemented Countable interface, 1 will be returned. There
>   is one exception, if var is NULL, 0 will be returned.

you could try this,

```
if (!method_exists($someVar, 'count') && !(is_array($someVar))) {
    echo 'cannot count';
}
else {
    echo count($someVar);
}
```

This should work with arrays, objects and simple variables.

Answer (score 0):

By "uncountable" you mean "not an array/object"?

If so test that using phps is_array() and is_object(), see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php

If you refer to special crafted arrays or objects that do not implement the countable pattern, then usually there is a reason for that. Most likely counting the elements in that structure does not make sense. In that case, first check if the array is countable by using method_exists($your_obj,'count').

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [is_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) function to check if the variable is an array or something else.

```
is_array($array)
```